# Node server didn't handle 1500 users on express api setup with cluster module

Tags: node.js

I setup the node server with the cluster module along with PM2 on AWS on centos . I suddenly notice that the server is not handling the 1500 users and keep the users in the queue till 20-33 seconds before sending the response . I want to make our app to responde every user in ms . I setup the httpServer . Can you please help to figure out the things

Code :

```
const raw = fs.createReadStream(`${scriptFilePath}/${scriptFile}.min.js`);
console.log('Process end:', new Date());
if (/\bdeflate\b/.test(acceptEncoding)) {
    res.cookie('sid', (req.session.cookie.sessionId ? '' : req.session.cookie.sessionId));
    req.session.save()
    res.writeHead(200, {
        'Content-Encoding': 'deflate',
        'content-type': 'text/javascript',
        'cache': true
    });
    raw.pipe(zlib.createDeflate()).pipe(res);

} else if (/\bgzip\b/.test(acceptEncoding)) {
    res.cookie('sid', (req.session.cookie.sessionId ? '' : req.session.cookie.sessionId));
    req.session.save()
    res.writeHead(200, {
        'Content-Encoding': 'gzip',
        'content-type': 'text/javascript',
        'cache': true
    });
    raw.pipe(zlib.createGzip()).pipe(res);

} else if (/\bbr\b/.test(acceptEncoding)) {
    res.cookie('sid', (req.session.cookie.sessionId ? '' : req.session.cookie.sessionId));
    req.session.save()
    res.writeHead(200, {
        'Content-Encoding': 'br',
        'content-type': 'text/javascript',
        'cache': true
    });
    raw.pipe(zlib.createBrotliCompress()).pipe(res);

} else {
    res.cookie('sid', (req.session.cookie.sessionId ? '' : req.session.cookie.sessionId));
    req.session.save()
    res.writeHead(200, {
        'content-type': 'text/javascript',
        'cache': true
    });
    raw.pipe(res);

}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: can you put a screenshot of "pm2 monit"  and "pm2 describe <<Process Number>> "commands in the server. And also please post the metadata information.

Comment: It wont be able to handle even 2 requests on the same route. You need to create a readStream for each request :)

Comment: @Naveen Kerati Can you please check.

Comment: @Bwaxxlo How will you handle to send script file in response ?

Comment: For what it's worth, the delivery of static files like `whatever.min.js`, is handled very nicely indeed by nginx. Instead of writing your own compression code, why not just use nginx? It should already be rigged if you're loadbalancing a lot of nodejs instances.

Comment: @O. Jones Thanks for the reply . Actually these files are creating dynamically . So i need to add some checks whether a script is active or inactive .